# Efficiently check if record exists in database using Entity framework LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to check if customer by code already exists in the database using entity framework. Ideally I would write plain sql query like this:

```
select id from dbo.Customer where RecActive = 1 and Code = 'xxx';
```

If query result is empty, it means customer by code 'xxx' does not exist yet. In entity framework there are multiple ways to write this, but I'm looking **the one nearest above**. **Note: Code field has unique index on it**

```
  using (var context = new CustomerContext())
  {
    // not very efficient as it reads all columns
    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode).SingleOrDefault() != null ? true : false;

    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode).Count() > 0 ? true : false;

    // translates to this query:
    // exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id]
    // FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
    //        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    //        FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
    //        WHERE ([Extent1].[RecActive] = 1) AND (([Extent1].[Code] = 
    //          @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[Code] IS NULL) AND 
    //          (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
    //        )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'xxx'
    int a = context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode).Select(c => c.Id).SingleOrDefault();             
    return a > 0 ? true : false;

    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode).Any();
  }
```

Perhaps any other good (performance alternative)? Note: **I have to use entity framework linq and not raw queries (which I would really like)** as linq is used throughout whole project consistently.

Comment: return context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode).Any();

Comment: *Why* do you need something like that? Are you trying to write an UPSERT method? If `Code` is the primary key EF will perform the check itself before inserting or updating. If you want to check for existence for some other reason use `Any()`. If you want the ID use `.Where()...).Select(c=>c.id)`

Comment: Why `<condition> ? true : false` - seems redundant to me.

Comment: `Any()` will likely use `select null` in its query and rather than `select id`. It's a very minor difference, but the question is round about in both asking that it matches that minor inefficiency of the original query and also asking that it be the most performant.

Answer (score 9):

Since your code ignores the actual ID, and returns only a `true`/`false` indication of its presence, you can do it with an single call of [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
return context.Customers.Any(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check for existence only, use `.Any()`. If you want to retrieve the ID(s) that match the criteria, use `Select`, eg :

```
 context.Customers
        .Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode)
        .Select(c => c.id);
```

If multiple IDs are a valid result, your method should return an array of strings/integers, whatever the type of `id` is. You can return an array of IDs with `.ToArray();`

```
 return context.Customers
               .Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode)
               .Select(c => c.id)
               .ToArray();
```

If you *don't* expect multiple IDs, you have to decide what to do if you get multiples results:

- `FirstOrDefault()` will return the first ID without throwing if there are multiple results.
- `SingleOrDefault()` will throw if there are multiple results preventing the use of a possibly invalid ID.

For example:

```
return context.Customers.Where(c => c.RecActive && c.Code == customerCode)
               .Select(c => c.id)
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking the existence of multiple entities with a composite PK I came up with the following:

```
// Returns the subset of entities that don't exist in the db.
private IReadOnlyList<TEntity> GetNewEntities<TEntity>(
    IEnumerable<TEntity> entities,
    Func<TEntity, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> getPredicate) where TEntity : class
{
    var newEntities = new List<TEntity>();
    foreach (var entitiesBatch in entities.Batch(100))
    {
        var entitiesExistence = GetEntitiesExistence(entitiesBatch, getPredicate);
        newEntities.AddRange(entitiesBatch
            .Where((_, i) => !entitiesExistence[i]));
    }

    return newEntities;
}

private IReadOnlyList<bool> GetEntitiesExistence<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, Func<T, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> getPredicate) where T : class
{
    IQueryable<bool> query = null;
    var set = this.dataEntities.Set<T>();
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var tempQuery = set.Where(getPredicate(entity))
            .Select(x => true)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(false);
        query = query == null ? tempQuery : query.Concat(tempQuery);
    }
    return query.ToArray();
}
```

getPredicate specifies the equality between 2 entities, it could be:

```
e1 => e2 =>
    e1.Key1 == e2.Key1 &&
    e1.Key2 == e2.Key2
```

Experiment with batch size for performance.
Usage example:

```
var newUsers = GetNewEntities(users,
    u1 => u2 =>
        u1.FirstName == u2.FirstName &&
        u1.LastName == u2.LastName);
```